# How to simplify array into only unique values in Python

Tags: php, python, arrays, numpy

Because of array depth issues in PHP, receiving this array from Python becomes truncated with an ellipsis ("..."). I'd like to process the array in Python before returning back to php.

Clarification: I need to maintain the inner sets [135, 121, 81]. These are R, G, B values and I'm tying to group sets that occur more than once. Values in sets need to maintain [1, 2, 3] sequence, NOT [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] as some answers have suggested below.

**How would you simplify this 3D `numpy.ndarray` to a collection of unique RGB triples?**

Here is how the array is printed by Python:

```
[[[135 121  81]
  [135 121  81]
  [135 121  81]
  ..., 
  [135 121  81]
  [135 121  81]
  [135 121  81]]

 [[135 121  81]
  [135 121  81]
  [135 121  81]
  ..., 
  [135 121  81]
  [135 121  81]
  [135 121  81]]

 [[ 67  68  29]
  [135 121  81]
  [ 67  68  29]
  ..., 
  [135 121  81]
  [135 121  81]
  [135 121  81]]

 ..., 
 [[200 170  19]
  [200 170  19]
  [200 170  19]
  ..., 
  [ 67  68  29]
  [ 67  68  29]
  [ 67  68  29]]

 [[200 170  19]
  [200 170  19]
  [200 170  19]
  ..., 
  [116 146  15]
  [116 146  15]
  [116 146  15]]

 [[200 170  19]
  [200 170  19]
  [200 170  19]
  ..., 
  [116 146  15]
  [116 146  15]
  [116 146  15]]]
```

Here is the code that I have attempted:

```
def uniquify(arr)
    keys = []

    for c in arr:
        if not c in keys:
            keys[c] = 1
        else:
            keys[c] += 1

    return keys

result = uniquify(items)
```

Comment: That doesn't look like python code ... Can you show what the python "array" looks like?

Comment: I've updated the code to show the python array.

Comment: 2D Array. Question was not fully updated at the same time.

Comment: @stwhite: OK, I'll change my answer to put the 2D answer first, instead of as an afterthought. But what's there should already work.

Comment: Meanwhile, it would be simpler if you posted the expected output, instead of trying to describe it.

Comment: It would also be simpler if you posted the input in a format that's directly usable in Python code. It took me 4 lines of code to process your input into something reasonable, vs. only 1 line to solve your problem…

Comment: For future reference: If you're using `numpy`, always say so in the question. It's almost always better to keep the data inside `numpy` as long as possible (for flexibility and simplicity, even if you don't care about the much-better performance), but you're not going to get the best answer unless someone like mgilson happens to guess right. (Fortunately, mgilson is around very often, and is smart enough to guess right far more often than you'd expect from a normal mortal… but you still shouldn't count on that.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the representation of your "array", it looks like you're working with a `numpy.ndarray`.  This becomes quite a simple problem if that is the case -- You can transform to a 1-D iterable simple by using the `.flat` attribute.  To make it unique, you can just use a `set`:

```
set(array.flat)
```

This will give you a set, but you could easily get a list from it:

```
list(set(array.flat))
```

Here's how it works:

```
>>> array = np.zeros((10,12,42,53))
>>> list(set(array.flat))
[0.0]
```

As a side note, there's also `np.unique` which will give you the unique elements of your array as well.

```
>>> array = np.zeros((10,12),dtype=int)
>>> print array
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
>>> np.unique(array)
array([0])
>>> array[0,5] = 1
>>> array[4,10] = 42
>>> np.unique(array)
array([ 0,  1, 42])
```

---

I think I finally got this one figured out:

```
from itertools import product

items = set(tuple(a[itr+(slice(None),)]) for itr in product(*[range(x) for x in a.shape[:-1]]))
print items
```

Seems to work.  Phew!

How this works -- the pieces that you want to keep as triplets are accessed as:

```
array[X,Y,:]
```

So, we just need to loop over all of the combinations of `X` and `Y`.  That is exactly what `itertools.product` is good for.  We can get the valid `X` and `Y` in an arbitrary number of dimensions:

```
[range(x) for x in array.shape[:-1]]
```

So we pass that to product:

```
indices_generator = product(*[range(x) for x in array.shape[:-1]])
```

Now we have something that will generate the first to indices -- We just need to construct a tuple to pass to `__getitem__` that numpy will interpret as `(X,Y,:)` -- That's easy, we're already getting `(X,Y)` from indices_generator -- We just need to tack on an emtpy slice:

```
all_items = ( array[idx+(slice(None),)] for idx in indices_generator )
```

Now we can loop over all_items looking for the unique ones with a set:

```
unique_items = set(tuple(item) for item in all_items)
```

Now turn this back into a list, or a numpy array or whatever you want for the purposes of passing it back to PHP.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It's close, but I forgot to mention that I need to maintain the inner sets [135, 121, 81]. These are R, G, B values and I'm tying to group sets that occur more than once.

Comment: @stwhite: Are you actually using a 3D `numpy` array, as mgilson suspected? Or a `list` of `list`s of `list`s, as it sounds like from your question? Or something in between, like a `list` of 2D `np.array`s or something?

Comment: @abarnert I am using numpy. I would assume it's only 3D, but I am measuring the same data right now... I wouldn't think numpy would use more dimensions dependent on data, but this is the first time I've used it.

Comment: @abarnert -- I suspected it was a numpy.ndarray because that's how they print (`__str__`).  They leave gaps with `...` and they don't put the commas in there.  It's a bit annoying actually, but I think they do a bit better if you specifcally look at their `__repr__`.

Comment: @mgilson really appreciate your help here. I realize this is another question in itself, but is there a way to count how many matches there are that get paired when doing the pairing? Eg. (255, 34, 52) found 10 times.

Comment: @stwhite -- What version of python are you using?  If you're using `python2.7` or newer, you can use a `collections.Counter` instead of a `set` in the very last line: `unique_items = Counter(tuple(item) for item in all_items)`.  This will give you a dictionary arranged so that the keys are the tuples and the values are the number of times it was found.

Comment: @stwhite -- I don't think so.   I should give you the number of times that particular tuple appears.  If that's wrong, I'd suggest you ask a new question (maybe with a link to this one).

Comment: @mgilson apologies. You are correct. I've removed my previous comment due to bad code on my end. I was running list(unique_items) after collections.Counter(). Thank you very much for all of your help & time.

Comment: @stwhite -- No problem.   I like to help progress happen :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the recipes in the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) documentation. There are `flatten` and `unique_everseen` functions that do exactly what you want.

So, you can copy and paste them. Or you can just [`pip install more-itertools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools) so you just import them. Now, you can flatten the 3D array to 2D, and uniquify the 2D array with `unique_everseen`…

Except for one problem. The elements of your 2D array are `list`s, which are not hashable, so you have to convert them to something hashable. But that's easy:

```
def uniquify(arr3d):
    return unique_everseen(flatten(arr3d), tuple)
```

That's it.

And if you look at the implementations of those functions while you're pasting them, they're pretty simple. The only real trick here is using a `set` to hold the values seen so far: sets only hold one copy of each unique element (and can determine whether an element is already in the set very quickly).

In fact, if you don't need to preserve the ordering, it's even simpler:

```
def uniquify(arr3d):
    return set(tuple(x) for x in flatten(arr3d))
```

As a test, I copied your string and turned it into an actual Python list display, then did this:

```
inarray = [[[135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81]],
           [[135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81]],
           [[67, 68, 29],
            [135, 121, 81],
            [67, 68, 29],
            [135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81],
            [135, 121, 81]],
           [[200, 170, 19],
            [200, 170, 19],
            [200, 170, 19],
            [67, 68, 29],
            [67, 68, 29],
            [67, 68, 29]],
           [[200, 170, 19],
            [200, 170, 19],
            [200, 170, 19],
            [116, 146, 15],
            [116, 146, 15],
            [116, 146, 15]],
           [[200, 170, 19],
            [200, 170, 19],
            [200, 170, 19],
            [116, 146, 15],
            [116, 146, 15],
            [116, 146, 15]]]
for val in uniquify(inarray):
    print(val)
```

The output was:

```
[135, 121, 81]
[67, 68, 29]
[200, 170, 19]
[116, 146, 15]
```

Is that what you wanted?

If you want it as a `list` of `list`s, that's just:

```
array2d = list(uniquify(array3d))
```

If you're used a simple `set` instead of `unique_everseen`, these will be `tuple`s instead of `list`s, so if you need a `list` of `list`s:

```
array2d = [list(val) for val in uniquify(array3d)]
```

Comment: I'm getting a `NameError: global name 'flatten' is not defined` error on this. Tried `intertools.flatten(arr3d)` but it throws `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'flatten'`

Comment: As the answer directly says, you have to either copy and paste them from the documentation, or import them from `more_itertools` after installing it.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` is your friend here:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> array = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6,6]
>>> [x[0] for x in itertools.groupby(array)]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

For example:

```
array = [[[135,121,81],
          [135,121,81],
          [135,121,81],
          [135,121,81],
          [135,121,81],
          [135,121,81]],
         [[135,121,81],
          [135,121,81],
          [135,121,81],
          [135,121,81],
          [135,121,81],
          [135,121,81]],
         [[67,68,29],
          [135,121,81],
          [67,68,29],
          [135,121,81],
          [135,121,81],
          [135,121,81]]]

import itertools

new_array = list()
for inner in array:
    new_inner = [x[0] for x in itertools.groupby(inner)]
    new_array.append(new_inner)
```

Produces:

```
[ [ [135, 121, 81] ], 
  [ [135, 121, 81] ],
  [ [67, 68, 29],
    [135, 121, 81],
    [67, 68, 29],
    [135, 121, 81] ] ]
```

Not quite unique, but you can sort `inner` to get only unique.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP actually wants. For one thing, he has a 3D array, not a 1D one. For another, it's not sorted, and `groupby` will only eliminate contiguous runs of a value, not any previous-seen value.

Comment: quite possible, I'm not very clear on what the output should be.

Comment: Sorting `inner` doesn't get only unique values; you still end up with 3 copies of `[138, 121, 81]`. Also, you're returning a 3D array, but the question specifically asks for a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the python `list` looks like `[[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9]]]` (that is, a `list` of `list`s of `integers`

```
mylist = [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9]]]
items = set()
for sublist in mylist:
    for subsublist in sublist:
        for item in subsublist:
            items.add(item)
```

If you then specifically need a `list`, you can just cast it as so: `items = list(items)`

A `set` is a datatype that is similar to a `list`, but doesn't contain duplicates.
A side-effect of the `set` datatype is the insertion order isn't preserved - if this is important to you you'll need something like:

```
mylist = [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9]]]
items = []
for sublist in mylist:
    for subsublist in sublist:
        for item in subsublist:
            if not item in items:
                items.add(item)
```

Edit: based on your edit, you probably want this:

```
mylist = [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9], [1,2,3]]]
items = []
for sublist in mylist:
    for item in sublist:
        if not item in items:
            items.append(item)
# items = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```